# Allow access to Activity Log via API

Tags: smartsheet-api

Is access to the Activity Log on the short term road map?

I have two use cases:

Compliance: 
Weekly dump of the Activity Logs, consolidate, and provide compliance metrics during initial adoption of the system.

Non-Compliance:
Weekly dump of the Activity Logs, consolidate, and provide compliance metrics and comparison to user list to determine non-compliance/resistance during initial adoption of the system.

Of course, those could continue after roll-out, but may be key to identifying areas of resistance to adoption and things to be improved early in the process.

I use Python 3.6 with associated SDK.

Craig

Answer (score 1):

It's on our list, but I can't say "short term."
It's relatively expensive due to the large list of activities we need to model.

Thank you for including the use cases - that really helps us prioritize.